# How do I show a return message when there are no data to be displayed in my tableview?

Tags: ios, swift, tableview

I am trying to display a return statement of "There are no emails" when there are no email data displayed in the tableview. However it is to no avail. Did I used the wrong variable or function calling/type etc.? How do I solve this?

These are the codes that I've tried and it kept on asking me to put it to a private func instead to silent a warning. Even so, I still couldn't get the return statement to show.

```
func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, titleForFooterInSection section: Int) -> Any? {
    if listOfMessages.count == 0 {
        return "There are no messages"
    }

    return (listOfMessages.count)
}
```

This is the warning that I was given:

> Instance method 'tableView(*:titleForFooterInSection:)' nearly matches optional requirement 'tableView(*:titleForFooterInSection:)' of protocol 'UITableViewDataSource'

These are the new codes that I wrote after I was suggested to add a UILabel and set its properties to Hidden.

```
func showLabel() {
    if listOfMessages.count == 0 {
        label.isHidden = true 
    } else {
        label.isHidden = false
    }
}
```

Still I am not able to get the desired outcome. The label stayed hidden.

Comment: If there are no items in the section, they section won't be displayed ... from memory

Comment: Where are you calling showLabel()?  Are you calling that when you reload the tableview?

Comment: Looks like your logic is wrong, it should be flipped to `if listOfMessages.count == 0 { label.isHidden = false } else { label.isHidden = false }`

Comment: Where have you added the `label`?

Comment: Also, what kind of array is `listOfMessages`?

Comment: I am trying to call the showLabel when I reload the tableview yes and I have changed the logic. Is there a reason why it still won't work? I added the label at the top using (@IBOutlet weak var label: UILabel!). That array is for the emails that I get from server into the mobile app

Answer (score 2):

Add a **UILabel** to the view with the text "*There are no messages*", set its center to the center of the view, or where ever you want to display it.

Initially set its **isHidden** property to **true**, and if the

```
listOfMessages.count == 0
```

update its **isHidden** to **false**.

**UPDATE**
Updating answer based on your question update:
Your isHidden logic is wrong, it should be:

```
func showLabel() {
    if listOfMessages.count == 0 {
        label.isHidden = true 
    } else {
        label.isHidden = false
    }
}
```

and don't forget to call that function when you update your datasource/reload your tableview

Answer (score 0):

1. You can create a separate cell in UITableView, if not getting data in array import condition in numberOfRows/numberOfSection and return this cell.
2. You can create a separate view and show either table view or that view on condition basis.

Answer (score 0):

you can use this:

```
func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, numberOfRowsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
    if listOfMessages.count == 0{
        let emptyLabel = UILabel(frame: CGRect(x: 0, y: 0, width: self.view.bounds.size.width, height: self.view.bounds.size.height))
        emptyLabel.text = "There are no messages"
        emptyLabel.textAlignment = NSTextAlignment.center
        self.tableview.backgroundView = emptyLabel
        self.tableview.separatorStyle = .none
        return 0
    } else {
        return listOfMessages.count
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Create an extension of `UITableView` like this way. call this extension method in your `UITableView` delegate method.

```
func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, numberOfRowsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
     items.count == 0 ? tableView.setEmptyMessage("Your message") : 
     tableView.restore()

     return items.count
  }
}

extension UITableView {

    func setEmptyMessage(_ message: String) {
        let messageLabel = UILabel(frame: CGRect(x: 0, y: 0, width: self.bounds.size.width, height: self.bounds.size.height))
        messageLabel.text = message
        messageLabel.textColor = .black
        messageLabel.numberOfLines = 0;
        messageLabel.textAlignment = .center;
        messageLabel.font = UIFont.systemFont(ofSize: 17)
        messageLabel.sizeToFit()

        self.backgroundView = messageLabel;
        self.separatorStyle = .none;
   }

   func restore() {
      self.backgroundView = nil
      self.separatorStyle = .singleLine
   }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

First of all, the method **`tableView(_: titleForFooterInSection:)`** will only get the call if there are any visible sections in the `tableView`.

Since there are 0 `rows` in all `sections`, the method won't execute.

**Solution:**

Now, the simplest way you can handle it is add a `UILabel` in the `UIViewController` where your `tableView` is added.

Now, you must be using any API call to fill your `listOfMessages` `array`. Now, instead of simply reloading the table, you need to check if `listOfMessages` is empty or not and hide/show the above added `label` accordingly.

Assuming that `listOfMessages` is of type `[String]`, you can add the below code in its `didSet` observer like so,

```
var listOfMessages = [String]() {
    didSet {
        label.isHidden = !self.listOfMessages.isEmpty
        tableView.reloadData()
    }
}
```

Whenever there is any change in `listOfMessages` value, the changes will be made as per its current state.